# Defining index for scattered polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have 50m X 200m polygon which has several small polygons inside. I would like to define how scattered small polygons inside a big polygon. I was wondering if there is a tool which can calculate some index based on the distribution of polygons across a big polygon. For example, if polygons are gathered it would give index 0 and if they are scattered well index would be 1. Is there any tool that I can use? ArcGIS or QGIS would be good.

Comment: Do you mean something like spatial homogeneity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_descriptive_statistics#Measures_of_spatial_homogeneity?

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS's Spatial Analyst toolset has

- [Spatial Auto-correlation tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/spatial-autocorrelation.htm)

  > Measures spatial autocorrelation based on feature locations and attribute values using the Global Moran's I statistic.
- [Multi-Distance Spatial Cluster Analysis (Ripley's K Function)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/multi-distance-spatial-cluster-analysis.htm)

  > Determines whether features, or the values associated with features, exhibit statistically significant clustering or dispersion over a range of distances.

I don't see any tool in QGIS that definitely does the same thing. Here are a few things that look like they might do something relevant.

- The SAGA `Spatial point pattern analysis` tool provides "a simple indication of the spatial distribution of points." This tool has a tutorial [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/spatial_statistics.html#moderate-fa-spatial-point-pattern-analysis). The `centroids` tool will convert your polygons to points so you can run the spatial point pattern analysis tool.
- QGIS also has various cluster analysis tools. Most of them just divide points up into clusters without providing any measure of "clustered-ness" (ie spatial homo/heterogeneity).
- The Visualist plugin has the tag `spatial autocorrelation map`.
- Per user30184's comment, you could try to implement the spatial homogeneity measures (Ripley's K and L functions) explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_descriptive_statistics#Measures_of_spatial_homogeneity). Ripley's K function is explained in more detail in [this article](https://doi.org/10.2307/3212829). Here are a few tips/suggestions:

  - As above, convert the small polygons to points.
  - Use the `distance matrix` tool to calculate the distance between each pair of points (this will provide the d<sub>ij</sub> values).